# Get function value (1/0) to integer

Tags: c

So I have this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

/* copy input to output; 2nd version  */

main()   {
int c;

while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
    putchar(c);
    }
}
```

What I want to do is to answer this question: "Verify that the expression getchar() != EOF is 0 or 1. "

I thought about doing like this but it did not work:

```
#include <stdio.h>

/* copy input to output; 2nd version  */

main()   {
int c;
int a;

int a = while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
    putchar(c);
    }
printf("%d", a);
}
```

How can I answer that question?/Get that value of the expression (getchar() != EOF) to an integer so I can see it?

Edit: So because the program runs it means the value is 1 (true), according to me.

Comment: Please throw your C book away and buy a more recent one. ;-) You seem to be learning from an edition that has been outdated for several decades.

Comment: @KonradRudolph. Please explain why

Comment: `int a, c; while (a = ((c = getchar()) != EOF)) { /* use a and c */ }`

Comment: @Methodius. If you're in the loop, the expression is 1. After the loop, it's 0. That's how a loop condition works.

Comment: @MadPhysicist Because implicit `int` hasn’t been valid C since C99, IIRC.

Comment: Consider reading [*Modern C*](https://modernc.gforge.inria.fr/) then [n1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf). Budget a week of work for reading these. Take inspiration from existing free software coded in C, such as [GNU make](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/) or [GNU bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/) whose source code you are allowed to download, study, and improve. Use also the [GDB](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/) debugger. Compile your C code with [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) invoked as `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`

Comment: How about just checking the value of `c` ?

Comment: `"Verify that the expression getchar() != EOF is 0 or 1."` The result of a boolean operation is always 0 or 1, this is not something you have to verify, this is by definition (C standard).

Comment: @xhienne: The fact that a document, even one that is a commonly accepted standard approved by a committee and backed by an international organization, says that something is 0 or 1 does not imply that a C implementation produced by flawed humans does not itself contain flaws and produce a value other than 0 or 1. For that matter, not all C implementations are intended to be standard C implementations—conformance to the standard is **voluntary**. “Verify” means to make sure or demonstrate for oneself, not to rely on reasoning from other factors.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. I understand it just is the value 1 because the function runs. I am impressed by Basile Starynkevitch information about C which looks very deep in a way. Thats nice and it can come to good use.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Can you name a compiler that doesn't comply with this definition? Anyway, it's obvious from the OP's question that the OP is not evaluating their compiler. Otherwise, the question would not be asked that way.

Comment: @xhienne: The existence of such a compiler is irrelevant to the meaning of “verify.” It still means to check for oneself. I disagree that is obvious and do not see why the question would not be asked that way. This could well be a teacher wanting students to see for themselves that `!=` produces 0 or 1 and not sometimes the difference between the two operands, as some people sometimes think `strcmp` returns (which we know since we occasionally get questions about it).

Comment: @EricPostpischil `I disagree that is obvious...` If I ask you to verify that a boolean is 0 or 1 and in return you provide me a loop around getchar(), then this is the last time I want you in my development team.

Comment: @xhienne: The result of `!=` is `int`, not Boolean or `_Bool`, per C 2018 6.5.9 3. So I am not particularly impressed with the quality of your development team.

Comment: @xhienne To be fair, assignment inside condition isn't a good idea to begin with. That bad practice is inherited by the OP from K&R, and the only sound way around it is to rewrite the loop. `while(a = ((c = getchar()) != EOF))` works, but it ain't pretty.

Answer (score 0):

To verify that `getchar() != EOF` is 0 or 1, you can simply print it:

```
printf("%d\n", getchar() != EOF);
```

Alternatively, you can record the value and test it in the program:

```
int v = getchar() != EOF;
if (v == 0 || v == 1)
    printf("getchar() != EOF is 0 or 1.\n");
else
    printf("getchar() != EOF is not 0 or 1.\n");
```

If you want to both verify the value is 0 or 1 and use the result of `getchar`, you must record both:

```
while (1)
{
    int c;
    int v = (c = getchar()) != EOF;
    if (v == 0 || v == 1)
        printf("getchar() != EOF is 0 or 1.\n");
    else
        printf("getchar() != EOF is not 0 or 1.\n");
    if (!v)
        break;
    putchar(c);
}
```